# Is $(\mathbb{Q^+},\cdot)$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

the case of the group $(\mathbb{Q^+},\cdot)$, is it cyclic (that is, a group that is generated by a single element)?

If each element is multiplied by another in a pair, then the only way to reverse that operation is division. But for fractions, it means for instance:

$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{8} $

but its reverse is:

$\frac{1}{2} / \frac{1}{4}=2 $

So this does not seem to be cyclic. But is this sufficient to show for non-cyclicity?

Thanks

Comment: For a group to be cyclic, it needs to be generated by a single element. Is there a rational number $g$ such that for each (nonzero?) rational $r$, there is a $k$ whereby $g^k = r$?

Comment: Yes, $(1/1)^{1/1}=1/1$

Comment: What power of $1$ gives you $2$? You need to be able to generate *every* element with that single element.

Comment: I see. So 1 generates only 1 as a fraction, but no other element, thus it does not generate a group. Therefore it is not cyclic.

Comment: In your question, include the definition of "cyclic" that you want to use.  Eevee made one guess of what you mean.  But you should tell us!

Comment: OK! done thanks

Comment: Its only one element.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it generated confusion. It is meant Q+!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show it is not cyclic, you have to show that *no generator* can be chosen to generate the whole group. You showed in the comments that $1$ cannot be a generator, but this does not show the group is not cyclic. Obviously, $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ is a cyclic group, but you can prove $0$ is not a generator.

Hint: Suppose $x = 2/3 \in G$ were a generator.

- If $n > 0$, then $(2/3)^n = 2^n/3^n$. Clearly $1/5$ is not equal to this fraction, because:

$$\frac{2^n}{3^n} = \frac{1}{5} \implies 5 \times 2^n = 3^n \implies 5 | 3^n$$
(which is false).

- Similarly if $n<0$ then $1/5$ is not in the image, for a similar reason.

This proves that $2/3$ is not a generator either. This argument can be generalised to an arbitrary generator $p/q$, or even any finite set of generators. Can you see how to generalise the argument?

Comment: Thanks, I see that you tested a contradiction to prove that the group is not cyclic. I will remember that.